# Idiomatic way of handling a goroutine with one "return" value?

Tags: go, channel

Imagine I want to write a function that returns a random number divided by 2:

```
func randomIntInHalf() int {
    return rand.Int() / 2
}
```

But then I decide I want to build this function for concurrency so I end up with:

```
func randomIntInHalf(c chan<- int) {
    c <- rand.Int() / 2
}

func main() {
    // Generate 10 random ints in parallel
    amount := 10
    c := make(chan int, amount)

    for i := 0; i < amount; i++ {
        go randomIntInHalf(c)
    }

    for i := 0; i < amount; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }

    close(c)
}
```

I see some issues with this approach. For example, I require the caller to close the channel when it's done generating, making it possible that someone might call the function and leave the channel open indefinitely. It was sort of my understanding that you always want the sender to close the channel. A) is that true and b) is it even possible in this case? Is there a better way to write this code or approach this problem?

And, generally, is there a better, idiomatic approach for running a function in a parallel that only ever writes 1 (or a known N) value to the channel?

Thanks.

Comment: A) No. B) Write a normal function. If you insist on delivering the value via a channel then your approach is fine because of A. If you do not range over a channel there is no real need to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to close channels. Once it goes out of scope, it will be garbage collected. Closing a channel is usually used to send a `done` notification to the listener. So it is not even possible in your case.

Yours is an idiomatic approach for what you're trying to achieve, but not the only one. Some others (not necessarily idiomatic) that I can think of are:

- You can use a shared data structure and populate that from multiple goroutines with explicit synchronization,
- You can keep a separate result for each goroutine, and pass in a pointer to it. Each goroutine sets its result without a need for synchronization, and when everything is done, the caller works with the results.

Comment: I would not call these approaches "idiomatic". From Effective Go (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#concurrency): `Go encourages a different approach in which shared values are passed around on channels and, in fact, never actively shared by separate threads of execution.`

Comment: @EmilePels fair point. Noted that in the answer.